# How to return the last values or variables of the method ,when 2 or more methods used in a class in python

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, raspberry-pi2

I have written a code using Tkinter in python.I have initially created two buttons,which are namely Room1 and Room2. So, when one of this button is clicked it creates another two buttons which indicates 2 buttons for each room.the flow is as shown below:

Room1-->  1_light_1 and 1_light_2  (2 buttons created when Room1 is clicked)

Room2-->  2_light_1 and 2_light_2   (2 buttons created when Room2 is clicked)

Now button are created and I use them to ON and OFF the LED.Now,there are two problems:

1)Now,I am in Room1 and I have two switches 1_light_1 and 1_light_2 .When I click one of those buttons in Room1 they make LED ON and they turn to Green color and now I am switching to Room2 and click on one of the buttons they make LED ON and turn green in color .If i make LED off they turn to Grey color.The problem is when I go back to Room1 the LED is ON but my button is not Green in color and is same when I switch to Room2.It might be some default color.So,please help me resolve this issue.I want to retain the color.

2)Always when I switch from one room to the other the buttons are created one over the other(I want the grid to be fixed).you can clearly observe this by changing the size of buttons on any of the rooms.But I only want to have buttons of that room.

code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

from Tkinter import *

class GUI():

    def __init__(self,master=None):

        self.master=master
        self.button1=Button(master,text="ROOM 1",width=6,height=4,command=self.show_Room1_buttons,bd=2)
        self.button1.grid(row=0,column=0)
        self.button2=Button(master,text="ROOM 2",width=6,height=4,command=self.show_Room2_buttons,bd=2)
        self.button2.grid(row=1,column=0)
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
        GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(12,GPIIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(15,GPIIO.OUT)

    def show_Room1_buttons(self):

        self.toggleButton11=Button(self.master,text="1_light1",width=6,height=6,bd=2,command=self.toggle1)
        self.toggleButton11.grid(row=1,column=2)
        self.label=Label(root,fg='Black',width=5,height=2,anchor=CENTER)
        self.label.grid(row=1,column=3)
        self.toggleButton12=Button(self.master,text="2_light2",width=6,height=6,bd=2,command=self.toggle2)
        self.toggleButton12.grid(row=1,column=4)

    def show_Room2_buttons(self):

        self.toggleButton21=Button(self.master,text="2_light1",width=6,height=6,bd=2,command=self.toggle3)
        self.toggleButton21.grid(row=1,column=2)

        self.label2=Label(root,fg='Black',width=5,height=2,anchor=CENTER)
        self.label2.grid(row=1,column=3)
        self.toggleButton22=Button(self.master,text="1_light2",width=6,height=6,bd=2,command=self.toggle4)
        self.toggleButton22.grid(row=1,column=4)

    def toggle1(self):

        if (self.toggleButton11["activebackground"]=="Green"):

            self.toggleButton11.config(relief=RAISED)
            self.toggleButton11["bg"]="Grey"
            self.toggleButton11["activebackground"]="Grey"
            GPIO.output(11,0)
       else:
            self.toggleButton11["bg"]="Green"  
            self.toggleButton11["activebackground"]="Green"
            self.toggleButton11.config(relief=SUNKEN)
            GPIO.output(11,1)

    def toggle2(self):

        if (self.toggleButton12["activebackground"]=="Green"):

            self.toggleButton12.config(relief=RAISED)
            self.toggleButton12["bg"]="Grey"
            self.toggleButton12["activebackground"]="Grey"
            GPIO.output(12,0)
        else:
            self.toggleButton12["bg"]="Green"  
            self.toggleButton12["activebackground"]="Green"
            self.toggleButton12.config(relief=SUNKEN)
            GPIO.output(12,1)

    def toggle3(self):

        if (self.toggleButton21["activebackground"]=="Green"):

            self.toggleButton21.config(relief=RAISED)
            self.toggleButton21["bg"]="Grey"
            self.toggleButton21["activebackground"]="Grey"
            GPIO.output(13,0)
       else:
            self.toggleButton21["bg"]="Green"  
            self.toggleButton21["activebackground"]="Green"
            self.toggleButton21.config(relief=SUNKEN)
            GPIO.output(13,1)
    def toggle4(self):

        if (self.toggleButton22["activebackground"]=="Green"):

            self.toggleButton22.config(relief=RAISED)
            self.toggleButton22["bg"]="Grey"
            self.toggleButton22["activebackground"]="Grey"
            GPIO.output(15,0)

        else:
            self.toggleButton22["bg"]="Green"  
            self.toggleButton22["activebackground"]="Green"
            self.toggleButton22.config(relief=SUNKEN)
            GPIO.output(15,1)
```

Comment: *The problem is when I go back to Room1 the LED is ON but my button is not Green in color*  Yes it is, the new button created is not.  Create one set of buttons (in __init__()) and grid_forget() http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm when leaving (int the above code, show_Room2_buttons would "forget" Room1 buttons).  Upon entering again, grid() the buttons again.  Creating who knows how many buttons will eventually slow down the computer.  Also, you can use one common function instead of all of the toggleX() functions.  Pass the the button id and the GPIO.output info to a common function.

Comment: Thank you @CurlyJoe , grid_forget() worked well.Can you please be more informative or can you please have small example how to retain the color of the button when i am switching between two methods.

Comment: Generally, you use a variable to store the state of anything, not just an LED or Button but anything you want to keep track of, and set the state to the stored value ("green" or "lightgray") when you grid() it.